# Simulating GUI delay / lag

Tags: windows, gratis, gui

For demonstration purposes regarding usability, I'm looking for a program that slows down mouse and keyboard input. The amount of delay should be adjustable say from 0 milliseconds to 1 second.

The app should run on Windows and not cost money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented [UI Delay Simulator](https://github.com/thomasw-mitutoyo-ctl/UI-Delay-Simulator) as a proof of concept. It's implemented in .NET, runs on Windows and is published under MIT license.

It delays mouse clicks and key presses by an adjustable timespan.

[image: Screenshot]